# Unusual USB keyboard wiring - repair needed

Tags: usb, wiring, repair, keyboard

New to anything electrical, and I'm trying to make an urgent fix for my wife's keyboard. She has a disability, so needs a specific keyboard to work, and the USB plug on the keyboard has been damaged and the male USB terminal is unlocatable. We're in lockdown (NZ) and it's likely to be a week or more before a replacement arrives.

I've done as much searching as I can, and I feel like splicing another USB cable onto the end of this one should be entirely doable.

BUT. The keyboard cable has 5 internal wires, and none of them are red. It has blue, green, black, white, and yellow. I've run on the assumption that yellow might be a faded red or orange, but wiring that and matching the others (replacement cable wiring is red white black and green, so leaving blue disconnected currently) hasn't produced anything. The keyboard manufacturer is Penclic - I've been unable to find anything useful about their wiring from my searches, but I don't know if there is a specific resource that might provide some help.

My question(s) is (are), which of these colours is most likely to be the +5v, or is it somehow unusual? And, is it possible to repair a 5 wire keyboard, by splicing with a 4 wire USB cable? Additionally, if I just keep trying combinations, am I likely to destroy something? Have I already??

TIA and apologies for anything important I forgot, or totally unnecessary detail I did include.[image: image showing keyboard wiring][image]

Additional images:
[image]N[image]

Glueless:
[image]

Macro:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Is that a "V" I spy?

Comment: Checking the other ends of the wires inside the keyboard would probably be a good next step.

Comment: using a multimeter / continuity tester...

Comment: Not sure if this helps at all @Hearth - have added a new image of the internals. Could potentially move the board but nervous about destroying the entire keyboard at this point!

Comment: Send more photos of the board! USB will be +5 and 0, fairly easy to identify on the board and important not to mix up. Then there's D+ and and D-, also easy to identify, not serious if you mix them up, it just won't work. Do you have a multimeter?

Comment: @tomnexus I do, I have almost no idea how to use it tho XD

I'll add more pictures of the board and of the multimeter, as I'm legitimately not even sure which setting is which...

Comment: Hit that glob of glue with some isopropyl alcohol, you'll be able to safely remove it after a bit.   Then shoot a high-res pic of the CIRCUIT BOARD (both sides).   By examining the PCB traces and what kind of components they connect to, we actually should be able to give a GOOD GUESS which wire is which.   D+/D- will be obvious.  Gnd also.   No promises but better than nothing.

Comment: From the first photo it's almost certain that Data are Green and Blue, Black is 0V and yellow or white is +5V. Figure out which and you can start trial and error with a sacrificed USB cable.

Comment: Get the glue off, there might be some words or other clues printed under it....

Comment: @KyleB thanks mate, have updated now.

Comment: Cheers, @tomnexus I'll get started on that soon.

Comment: So I take back my green/blue theory. There's a bit of reflection on the new photo. Find out which two wires go to the thin tracks under the writing C32. Those are D+ and D- in some order. White might be one of them. Then the odd one out is +5V (red on a normal cable)

Comment: Thanks @tomnexus, not sure if the new images help. I'm guessing it's yellow = D- (goes under c32 - I think?) , green is d+, blue is G (whatever that means) and I can't see what's under the white wire connection.

Comment: D+ D- S  G and V  are clearly marked.  Am I the only one seeing that???  S= shield G=Gnd, V= V+   Colors are irrelevant, you're gonna replace the whole cord, right?

Comment: @kyleb haha took me a couple of go's to get good angles of the letters, don't judge anyone but me  yeah I will, have just tested with a quick twist and it's working! Thanks

Comment: Thanks @tomnexus - twisted some wires and the keyboard is working! Will remove the solder and solder the new cable on. Thanks again!

Comment: @craigg123   Excellent brother.  Very happy it worked out for you!   Wishing the best for you and your wife.

Comment: Thank you @kyleb - it might seem minor, but for someone with her challenges and, with everything else going on, it was a big win today. Take care in this crazy world!

Comment: I'm glad it worked out. What location? I'm in Auckland and may be able to help generally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usb wire colors are a guideline but not mandatory. You should never actually assume a wires color will mean it's actually a specific function in any case. Always measure it.

The USB data lines will typically be two thin parallel tracks on a pcb. Finding which is which may be difficult without tracing them to an IC and having a datasheet to find out which pin should be which data line.

Power and ground are easier, as the ground plane tends to be bigger and the power lines bigger than data but smaller than ground. A capacitor with labeling would be best.

But as you see in your last pictures, there is markings on the board.

Ground seems to be blue.

Shield is black but it is just tied to ground with a 0 ohm resistor but they decided to solder unto a usb A connects shield instead. You can probably ignore that wire, **which answers your 5 wire vs 4 wire question**. If your replacement cable has a metal foil then that's what you should connect to the shield.

V+ may be white, with data - and data + the yellow and green but the wires are blocking the white letters that likely show D+ and D- and V+ or VCC.

Based on the last picture the board has a common gl850g usb 2.0 hub IC. The datasheet shows its pin outs and you can use your multimeter in continuity mode to confirm everything, it's a simple IC. https://www.kean.com.au/oshw/WR703N/GL850G%20USB%20Hub%201.07.pdf

***Frankly you should just ignore the original cables and colors. Desolder the wires, clean the board and trace the pins to the IC, and add your own cable as required.*** pins 23 5V in, 15 ground, 25, 26 usb upstream data pins, are all you need to figure out what's what.

Comment: Awesome, thank you @Passerby! I did a quick test by twisting the wires and it's working. I'll clean the solder off and do a proper job before it gets used. Really appreciate your help!